# Selecting a Particular Channel during CIPSEND in ESP8266

Tags: ip, wifi, at-command, esp8266

I have been working with the Esp8266 Wifi Module for a Project of logging data continuously onto a webpage. I have been using the following code to achieve my goal using the AT commands so far (as I don't want to use any pre made library).

```
AT
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CWJAP="MY_SSID","MY_PASSKEY"
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSERVER=1,80
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSEND=CHANNEL_NO,NO+OF_CHARACTERS_TO+BE_SENT
AT+CIPSEND=CHANNEL_NO,NO+OF_CHARACTERS_TO+BE_SENT
AT+CIPSEND=CHANNEL_NO,NO+OF_CHARACTERS_TO+BE_SENT
AT+CIPSEND=CHANNEL_NO,NO+OF_CHARACTERS_TO+BE_SENT
AT_CIPCLOSE=0
```

Now I'm continuously sending the data onto the webpage and alas closing the process using `AT+CIPCLOSE`. Now everytime i need to enter the static ip along with the port number (which is 80 in my case) which is obtained from the `AT_CIFSR` command. After the execution of this command the channel information is displayed on the serial terminal. And according to that channel number I have to change the Channel number parameter in `AT+CIPSEND` command. So my question is can we configure the ESP to a particular channel number for once and then continuously send the data without getting bothered about the Channel number???

Comment: if it is a channel problem, note that the AP must use the same channel as the STA

Comment: If you are sending the data to a webpage, why are you running a server on the ESP? And what kind of "channel"  are you talking about? `AT+CIFSR` only returns IPs and MACs.

Comment: Yes `AT+CIFSR` returns the IP address and i'm using one of that IP address to send my data to. I'm using the Station IP address that I get into the CIFSR command. So when I put that IP onto the browser there is a response to the ESP indicating the channel number which is open(connected) at that time. So i'm talking about that channel number.

Comment: Is your website, that you are logging data to, on the ESP8266? Is that why you are running a server on it and you are connecting from the browser to it? In that case, [multiple connections must be enabled](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CIPSERVER) and you need to use those connection ids because of it.

Comment: Yes @gre_gor. The IP on which i'm logging my data is the station IP address which we get while we execute `AT+CIFSR`. So every time I put that IP onto the browser I get a response of the channel id. So basically i'm sending data through ESP to a website or IP which is present on ESP which is connected to my local home network.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are referring to the ESP's connection number, not a wifi channel number. After gre_gor's comment I am not sure that I fully understand where the web page is.  The ESP8266 can support up to 4 connections, so your server will have to deal with them.  If you are replying to a request from a remote host, then you will need to respond using the correct connection number.  [Here is an example python program](https://github.com/guyz/pyesp8266/blob/master/esp8266server.py) that shows how to get the connection number from the request and use it in the response.

If you are really sending data to a web page on a remote server, try `AT+CIPMUX=0` instead of 1 which tells it there is only one channel.  After issuing that, you no longer need to specify channel number in AT+CIPSEND, as in `AT+CIPSEND=NO+OF_CHARACTERS_TO+BE_SENT`

Comment: You can only [create a server](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CIPSERVER) when you have set [CIPMUX=1](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CIPMUX).

Comment: Maybe I mis-read the problem.  What you said is true.  However if he's sending data to a web page then he might really be the client.  If he's really the server then he'll have to manage the connection numbers.

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding in conveying things here. Sorry.  Let me make it more clear. I am using the Esp module to connect to a local network (my home wifi for eg) Now I want to send some data over it and then extract that data. So Esp will be the client as it is sending data. So I used `CIPMUX=1` and then started a server at port 80. Then I got the station IP address using the `CIFSR`command and running that IP onto the browser I get a response on my terminal about the connection being made and the channel number etc. So if I use `CIPMUX=0` how will i able to send any data?

Comment: If you are browsing to your ESP device then it is the server, and you will have to parse out the channel number and use it in your transmissions to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

AP Channels at 802.11b/g/n is for creating multitude of communicating devices on same medium and avoiding interference. It is not client configurable. You can change it from your AP settings.

You only able to set specific channel when you are in AP mode with your ESP8266 to serve other clients.

Comment: So then what changes do I have to make to send the data onto a particular channel each time? Can you suggest those changes as i'm not getting any commands which will directly solve my purpose.

Comment: It is a config stands under your router settings. Launch to your router/modem/ap web interface by typing its IP to your browser. The channel settings are possibly laying under Wireless or WAN section.

Comment: Okay. So we can't do anything from the module's side?

Comment: In sta mode, you cant select ap channel, i am sorry.

Comment: @cagdas As I understand, he is talking about the connection id for `AT+CIPSEND` not the WiFi channel.

Comment: Yees gre_gor you are right. I think @leetibbett hit the issue.